# Application works with app.all but not with app.use... not sure why

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having some problems trying to implement some middleware in my app.
Specicially, the `app.use()` does not seem to catch and I don't understand why.
Below is roughly what I have.

**routes/index.js**

```
var Sessions = require('../events');  

module.exports = exports = function(app) {

  app.use(Sessions.isLoggedIn);

  //app.use() does not catch but this does
  //app.all('*', Sessions.isLoggedIn); 

  // Home Page
  app.get('/', displayHome);
  app.get('/:library/:books', displayLibrary);

}
```

**events.js**

```
module.exports = exports = {

  isLoggedIn: function(req, res, next) {
      console.log('isLoggedIn');
      return next();
}
```

Any suggestions as to why `app.use()` is not catching?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the configuration in **ape.js**

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.compress()); // compress responses
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(express.cookieParser('locket'));
  app.use(express.cookieSession({
    key: 'locket',
    secret: 'mySecret',
    cookie: {httpOnly: true, expires: 0, path: '/'}
  }));

  // cache every file going out
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!res.getHeader('Cache-Control')) {
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' + (86400 / 1000));
    }
    next();
  });

  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({showStack: true, dumpExceptions: true}));
});

routes(app);
```

Comment: Does it fire on home `/` ? also try to invoke it e.g `Sessions.isLoggedIn(par,am,s)`

Comment: It does not fire at all under `app.use`.  When `Sessions.isLoggedIn` is invoked is works fine.  Does not catch when used in conjunction with `app.use`.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. Are you sure you are exporting your routes correctly?

Comment: see update: added configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router is responding to the request before your middleware function has a chance to run.

app.js sets up several other middleware functions, then `use`s `app.router`.  You then call your routes/index.js file, which `use`s a new middleware function which gets added *after* `app.router`.

`use` your `isLoggedIn` function *before* the router, or use it specifically with the routes that need to check login state:

```
app.get('/', Sessions.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) { ... });
```